# org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess destroy message with Selenium 3.0, gecko 0.15, FF52

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Simple script:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class sanity {

public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium Purely\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
driver.get("http://facebook.com");
driver.quit();//closes the browser
} }
```

On execution completion, it throws below error in console.

1489404845805   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:34461
1489404846478   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\jshaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.ZsJREdq3xMm4
1489404846494   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args []
1489404846525   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:60729
1489404848161   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 60729
Mar 13, 2017 5:04:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
1489404862119   Marionette  INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted
[Child 4856] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2143
Mar 13, 2017 5:04:23 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess destroy
SEVERE: Unable to kill process with PID 11728

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest version of [selenium-java](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.seleniumhq.selenium%7Cselenium-java%7C3.3.1%7Cjar) (version 3.3.1 at the time of this writing).